# SHChangeNotifyRegister notifications on Windows 10 are inconsistent

Tags: winapi, notifications

I'm running Windows 10 and have an application that lists files in a folder along with the ability to delete a file inside the application. To delete a file in my application, I use `SHFileOperation`.

I would like changes to the folder contents to automatically update in my application if changes occur to that folder using the shell. I've been reading a lot of posts and done a lot of testing and am running into some inconsistencies in the behavior of the notification mechanism. Here are the sources and events that I send to `SHChangeNotifyRegister`:

```
fSources = SHCNRF_InterruptLevel | SHCNRF_NewDelivery | SHCNRF_ShellLevel
fEvents =
  SHCNE_CREATE | SHCNE_DELETE | SHCNE_RENAMEITEM | SHCNE_UPDATEITEM |
  SHCNE_MKDIR | SHCNE_RMDIR | SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER | SHCNE_UPDATEDIR
```

To keep things simple, I set the `fRecursive` flag in the change notify entry to false, and I do not set the `SHCNRF_RecursiveInterrupt` flag. I'm getting notification messages, but the events I'm seeing for different actions seem inconsistent. Let's suppose in my application I'm looking at notifications for a *target folder*. Then these are my results for various actions that I've observed ("Events" indicates what events are triggered as a result of the "Action"):

[image]

Ideally, I'd like take a single action on any one of these actions. I can cause some notifications not to occur, such as SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, if I remove the `SHCNRF_InterruptLevel` source, but then I lose a couple of the actions. The actions in the table that do not produce notifications (move and rename) will generate an SHCNE_EXTENDED_EVENT notification if I enable it, but then I get a slew of those notifications at various times for various actions and it becomes unmanageable. Oddly, renaming a file does not generate an SHCNE_RENAMEITEM event. If I remove the `SHCNRF_ShellLevel` source, then copying folders/files from zip files do not generate any notification.

Is there a way to get consistent notifications for these kinds of simple actions, or somehow otherwise filter these events so that I can determine if I am getting extra notifications for a given action?

Comment: If it's a real (filesystem) folder you're monitoring you may want to consider `ReadDirectoryChangesW` instead of using the shell's notification system.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This directly concerns work I'm doing.

Comment: @JonHarper I have not, but I had not yet tried the suggestion to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. I'm a bit skeptical of it, but it's probably worth a try. I just have not gotten back around to it.